# Weird regex behaviour datetime parsing

Tags: javascript, regex

I got super weird situation with regex in JavaScript:

```
/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2,4})\s+(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})\s*(AM|PM)$/
```

test string:

```
8/4/2016 12:00:0 AM
```

I tested it on: https://regex101.com/ and other similar pages.

Now - when I type test string it works, when I copy and paste it does not.
Super strange. Same in my JavaScript code, when I type it in my code it works, when I paste it does not.

I'm going crazy, I'm I missing something?

Comment: Check if you do not copy/paste any hidden symbols.

Comment: Check that you don't copy paste spaces before and / or after.

Comment: I think it got something to do with unicode - length of typed string is 16, length of passed string is 32. Is there way to tell RegExp to ignore unicode? The value tested is taked directly from HTML input.

Comment: Why don't you copy and paste the offending text right here in your post? Otherwise it's a guessing game. Also, _Unicode_ is encoded as utf-8/16/32, the string is interpreted as all Unicode or all _not_ Unicode. Regular expressions have to know how to interpret the encoded string. Only then can you _exclude_ Unicode characters from the match.